# Texture Paint is not showing proper color. Is my node tree at fault?

Tags: texturing, uv, transparency

[image: Nodetree]

[image]

Not sure if its an issue with my node tree or some of the settings on the side.

Comment: Hello please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F74_XVH2xWsCBupRxR6HtmW747Hhbx8x/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Hello, it asks for an authorization

Comment: Sorry! Try again. It should let you in now.

Answer (score 0):

Select the *Image Texture* node with makeup.png, put the *Strength* of the brush at 1, lower down the *Subsurface* value of the *Principled BSDF* at 0, or plug the *Image Texture* into the *Subsurface Color* input. Also does your mesh needs to be so high-poly?

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean my lowpoly model? What's crazy is that I did retopology for it and got the face count really low. Then, I added a modifier... and the poly count got higher. I'm wondering if I have to do retopology again.

Comment: if you've used a Subdivision Surface modifier, don't apply it unless you have a good reason

Comment: Noted. I do want to pose this character. Not much so animating it. Should I do retopology again? I don't know if you saw but I did bake a map for it.

Comment: If you plan to animate it's a very bad idea to have a high-poly object. To simplify it, try a Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide, and play with the Interations parameters in the Operator Box

Comment: But it will need to be re-paint afterwards because if you change the topology it will change the UVs

Comment: Okay, make sense. I don't plan to animate just pose like adding bones and what not. This is my first character, so I made a lot of mistakes in the beginning. Thank you